# Add date of submission to Cloudpages form/data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I currently have a page set up in CloudPages that includes a form. When someone fills out the form, the information goes into a saved data extension. Is there a way to automatically include the time that someone submitted the form to pull through into the data extension? This is my current AMPscript setup for bringing the filled out data into the extension:

```
%%[
set @A = RequestParameter(“A”)
set @B = RequestParameter(“B)


SET @InsertData = InsertData("XYZExtension", “A”, @A, “B”, 
 @B)

]%%
```

I've been looking online for a straightforward way to do this but haven't found anything.

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done without code.  The following works in E,ail Studio, not contact builder.
Add another field to your DE that has the type date, then a little plus symbol appears next to defaultValue. Press that to make the field use current Date as default value. you don't have to change the insert. Note this will be servertime, utc-6.

Comment: Thank you Jonas! This did work, but I went with the solution below just to keep time consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the clever and easy solution provided by Jonas in the comments, you can also use ampscript to do this for you:

```ampscript
%%[
set @systemDate  = Now(1)
set @localDate =  SystemDateToLocalDate(@systemDate)
set @A = RequestParameter("A")
set @B = RequestParameter("B")

set @InsertData = InsertData("XYZExtension", "A", @A, "B", 
 @B, "Inserted",@localdate)
]%%
```

The advantage of this solution is utilisation of [SystemDateToLocalDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SystemDateToLocalDate.htm), ensuring the timestamp will be stored in your local time, instead of utc-6 (being the default system time zone)

Comment: Thank you Lukas! Although Jonas's solution worked, this is what I went with to avoid any timezone confusion. Works perfectly.

Comment: You’re welcome @trh31625  - remember to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Cool :) Just to give another side to this. I am a huge fan of keeping all times in DEs in servertime until you make them customer facing or export them. Firstly, this helps you leverage such quick fixes, but more importantly, only dates that you store in systemtime are consistent with the timestamps that you cannot influence in SFMC. ->  consider: "is this timestamp newer than the customer's latest click?" >> this question is MUCH easier to answer if ALL times you store are systemTime, because dataviews like _click do.  call your field "timestampSystemTime" and it's hard to miss.